# How to insert a font icon in alert

Tags: angular, icons, nativescript, alert, nativescript-angular

I'm creating a cross-platform app with Nativescript and Angular. I want to insert a font icon as title for alert. I have a custom icon font with char codes that go from e900 to e906.

I set the text with `String.fromCharCode(0xe901)` but it gives a chinese ideogram.

I try to insert `<label class="ico"> + String.fromCharCode(0xe901) + </label>` but it's clearly wrong.

```
dialogs.confirm({
        title: "<label class=\"ico\">" + String.fromCharCode(0xe901) + "</label>",
        message: "Are you sure?",
        okButtonText: "Ok",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel"
    }).then(result => {
        //...some code...
    });
```

Is there a way to do this without any plugins?

I've already try [fancyalert](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fancyalert) but it seems that doesn't work with Angular.

Comment: The default alert dialog nor the fancyalert supports injecting custom components within dialog. You may only be able to show simple text, you can not inject a label inside. A workaround could be building your own custom dialog that would mimic the default dialog.

Comment: How can I build a custom dialog?